# Hybrid Deep Learning Applied to artificial data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

good evening, let us suppose that we have artificial data generated using following code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X ,y =make_classification(n_samples=5000,n_features=10,n_informative=3,random_state=1)
```

i have read following article about hybrid deep learning : [Hybrid Deep learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-hybrid-learning-a-fusion-of-conventional-ml-with-state-of-the-art-dl-cb43887fe14)

let us suppose i want to  use classical MLP(multilayer Perceptron) and  some  classical  ML algorithm, for instance  catboost, according article, i want following thing : as  you see from the code, informative is  three feature(all remaining 7 feature  is redundancy), therefore using MLP  somehow i want to extract important features and then apply  catboost, here is preparation for  MLP model in keras

```
import keras
from keras.models import  Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=30,input_dim=10,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=15,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

let us import catboost library

```
import catboost
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
```

please help me with a very simple  code how to  combine those stuff togerther(i mean use  MLP as  feature extraction and use catboostclassifier for classification). thanks a lot

Comment: u simply have to cut your trained network in the middle, extract features and then fit catboost on them

Comment: yes but how? that is actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to cut your trained network in the middle, wherever you like but paying attention that your network returns 2D data. Only in this way you can fit a tabular model.

In the example below, we fit a dense NN and then apply a RandomForest from sklearn on the hidden extracted features. You can modify the network or change the final tabular model

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

# create dummy data
X,y = make_classification(n_samples=5000, n_features=10, n_informative=3, random_state=1)

# fit NN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=30,input_dim=10,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=15,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y, epochs=10)

# extract feature from NN
extraction_model = Model(model.input, model.layers[1].output)
# in model.layers you can find all the list of available layers' output
# we select the output of our second Dense layer
# the second Dense return 2D data
new_X = extraction_model.predict(X) # (n_sample, hidden_dim)

# fit a tabular model
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(new_X, y)
print(rf.score(new_X, y))
```